# kubeflow pipeline Failed to execute component: unable to get pipeline with PipelineName

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

Install follow https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests in v1.4.1

KFP version: 1.7.0

KFP SDK version: build version dev_local

k3s Kubernetes 1.19

use demo example to add pipline

kfp 1.8.10

kfp-pipeline-spec 0.1.13

kfp-server-api 1.7.1

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import kfp
import kfp.dsl as dsl
from kfp.v2.dsl import component
from kfp import compiler

@component(
    base_image="library/python:3.7"
)
def add(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    '''Calculates sum of two arguments'''
    return a + b


@dsl.pipeline(
    name='v2add',
    description='An example pipeline that performs addition calculations.',
    # pipeline_root='gs://my-pipeline-root/example-pipeline'
)
def add_pipeline(a: float = 1, b: float = 7):
    add_task = add(a, b)


compiler.Compiler(
    mode=kfp.dsl.PipelineExecutionMode.V2_COMPATIBLE,
    launcher_image='library/gcr.io/ml-pipeline/kfp-launcher:1.8.7'
).compile(pipeline_func=add_pipeline, package_path='pipeline.yaml')
```

I upload the pipeline.yaml and start a run get error

logs

```
I1231 10:12:23.830486       1 launcher.go:144] PipelineRoot defaults to "minio://mlpipeline/v2/artifacts".
I1231 10:12:23.830866       1 cache.go:143] Cannot detect ml-pipeline in the same namespace, default to ml-pipeline.kubeflow:8887 as KFP endpoint.
I1231 10:12:23.830880       1 cache.go:120] Connecting to cache endpoint ml-pipeline.kubeflow:8887
F1231 10:12:23.832000       1 main.go:50] Failed to execute component: unable to get pipeline with PipelineName "pipeline/v2add" PipelineRunID "7e2bdeeb-aa6f-4109-a508-63a1be22267c": Failed GetContextByTypeAndName(type="system.Pipeline", name="pipeline/v2add")
```

pod

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: v2add-rzrht-37236994
  namespace: kubeflow-user-example-com
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kubeflow-user-example-com/pods/v2add-rzrht-37236994
  uid: 3ceb73e5-80b5-4844-8cc8-8f2bf61319d2
  resourceVersion: '28824661'
  creationTimestamp: '2021-12-31T10:12:21Z'
  labels:
    pipeline/runid: 7e2bdeeb-aa6f-4109-a508-63a1be22267c
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/cache_enabled: 'true'
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching: 'true'
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/kfp_sdk_version: 1.8.10
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline-sdk-type: kfp
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component: 'true'
    workflows.argoproj.io/completed: 'true'
    workflows.argoproj.io/workflow: v2add-rzrht
  annotations:
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/arguments.parameters: '{"a": "1", "b": "7"}'
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/component_ref: '{}'
    pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component: 'true'
    sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'false'
    workflows.argoproj.io/node-name: v2add-rzrht.add
    workflows.argoproj.io/outputs: >-
      {"artifacts":[{"name":"add-Output","path":"/tmp/outputs/Output/data"},{"name":"main-logs","s3":{"key":"artifacts/v2add-rzrht/2021/12/31/v2add-rzrht-37236994/main.log"}}]}
    workflows.argoproj.io/template: >-
      {"name":"add","inputs":{"parameters":[{"name":"a","value":"1"},{"name":"b","value":"7"},{"name":"pipeline-name","value":"pipeline/v2add"},{"name":"pipeline-root","value":""}]},"outputs":{"artifacts":[{"name":"add-Output","path":"/tmp/outputs/Output/data"}]},"metadata":{"annotations":{"pipelines.kubeflow.org/arguments.parameters":"{\"a\":
      \"1\", \"b\":
      \"7\"}","pipelines.kubeflow.org/component_ref":"{}","pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component":"true","sidecar.istio.io/inject":"false"},"labels":{"pipelines.kubeflow.org/cache_enabled":"true","pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching":"true","pipelines.kubeflow.org/kfp_sdk_version":"1.8.10","pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline-sdk-type":"kfp","pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component":"true"}},"container":{"name":"","image":"library/python:3.7","command":["/kfp-launcher/launch","--mlmd_server_address","$(METADATA_GRPC_SERVICE_HOST)","--mlmd_server_port","$(METADATA_GRPC_SERVICE_PORT)","--runtime_info_json","$(KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO)","--container_image","$(KFP_V2_IMAGE)","--task_name","add","--pipeline_name","pipeline/v2add","--run_id","$(KFP_RUN_ID)","--run_resource","workflows.argoproj.io/$(WORKFLOW_ID)","--namespace","$(KFP_NAMESPACE)","--pod_name","$(KFP_POD_NAME)","--pod_uid","$(KFP_POD_UID)","--pipeline_root","","--enable_caching","$(ENABLE_CACHING)","--","a=1","b=7","--"],"args":["sh","-c","\nif
      ! [ -x \"$(command -v pip)\" ]; then\n    python3 -m ensurepip || python3
      -m ensurepip --user || apt-get install
      python3-pip\nfi\n\nPIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 python3 -m pip install
      --quiet     --no-warn-script-location 'kfp==1.8.10' \u0026\u0026 \"$0\"
      \"$@\"\n","sh","-ec","program_path=$(mktemp -d)\nprintf \"%s\" \"$0\"
      \u003e \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"\npython3 -m
      kfp.v2.components.executor_main                        
      --component_module_path                        
      \"$program_path/ephemeral_component.py\"                        
      \"$@\"\n","\nimport kfp\nfrom kfp.v2 import dsl\nfrom kfp.v2.dsl import
      *\nfrom typing import *\n\ndef add(a: float, b: float) -\u003e float:\n   
      '''Calculates sum of two arguments'''\n    return a +
      b\n\n","--executor_input","{{$}}","--function_to_execute","add"],"envFrom":[{"configMapRef":{"name":"metadata-grpc-configmap","optional":true}}],"env":[{"name":"KFP_POD_NAME","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.name"}}},{"name":"KFP_POD_UID","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.uid"}}},{"name":"KFP_NAMESPACE","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.namespace"}}},{"name":"WORKFLOW_ID","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.labels['workflows.argoproj.io/workflow']"}}},{"name":"KFP_RUN_ID","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.labels['pipeline/runid']"}}},{"name":"ENABLE_CACHING","valueFrom":{"fieldRef":{"fieldPath":"metadata.labels['pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching']"}}},{"name":"KFP_V2_IMAGE","value":"library/python:3.7"},{"name":"KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO","value":"{\"inputParameters\":
      {\"a\": {\"type\": \"DOUBLE\"}, \"b\": {\"type\": \"DOUBLE\"}},
      \"inputArtifacts\": {}, \"outputParameters\": {\"Output\": {\"type\":
      \"DOUBLE\", \"path\": \"/tmp/outputs/Output/data\"}}, \"outputArtifacts\":
      {}}"}],"resources":{},"volumeMounts":[{"name":"kfp-launcher","mountPath":"/kfp-launcher"}]},"volumes":[{"name":"kfp-launcher"}],"initContainers":[{"name":"kfp-launcher","image":"library/gcr.io/ml-pipeline/kfp-launcher:1.8.7","command":["launcher","--copy","/kfp-launcher/launch"],"resources":{},"mirrorVolumeMounts":true}],"archiveLocation":{"archiveLogs":true,"s3":{"endpoint":"minio-service.kubeflow:9000","bucket":"mlpipeline","insecure":true,"accessKeySecret":{"name":"mlpipeline-minio-artifact","key":"accesskey"},"secretKeySecret":{"name":"mlpipeline-minio-artifact","key":"secretkey"},"key":"artifacts/v2add-rzrht/2021/12/31/v2add-rzrht-37236994"}}}
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
      kind: Workflow
      name: v2add-rzrht
      uid: 9a806b04-d5fa-49eb-9e46-7502bc3e7ac5
      controller: true
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
  managedFields:
    - manager: workflow-controller
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2021-12-31T10:12:21Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            .: {}
            'f:pipelines.kubeflow.org/arguments.parameters': {}
            'f:pipelines.kubeflow.org/component_ref': {}
            'f:pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component': {}
            'f:sidecar.istio.io/inject': {}
            'f:workflows.argoproj.io/node-name': {}
            'f:workflows.argoproj.io/template': {}
          'f:labels':
            .: {}
            'f:pipeline/runid': {}
            'f:pipelines.kubeflow.org/cache_enabled': {}
            'f:pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching': {}
            'f:pipelines.kubeflow.org/kfp_sdk_version': {}
            'f:pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline-sdk-type': {}
            'f:pipelines.kubeflow.org/v2_component': {}
            'f:workflows.argoproj.io/completed': {}
            'f:workflows.argoproj.io/workflow': {}
          'f:ownerReferences':
            .: {}
            'k:{"uid":"9a806b04-d5fa-49eb-9e46-7502bc3e7ac5"}':
              .: {}
              'f:apiVersion': {}
              'f:blockOwnerDeletion': {}
              'f:controller': {}
              'f:kind': {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:uid': {}
        'f:spec':
          'f:containers':
            'k:{"name":"main"}':
              .: {}
              'f:args': {}
              'f:command': {}
              'f:env':
                .: {}
                'k:{"name":"ARGO_CONTAINER_NAME"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
                'k:{"name":"ARGO_INCLUDE_SCRIPT_OUTPUT"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
                'k:{"name":"ENABLE_CACHING"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:valueFrom':
                    .: {}
                    'f:fieldRef':
                      .: {}
                      'f:apiVersion': {}
                      'f:fieldPath': {}
                'k:{"name":"KFP_NAMESPACE"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:valueFrom':
                    .: {}
                    'f:fieldRef':
                      .: {}
                      'f:apiVersion': {}
                      'f:fieldPath': {}
                'k:{"name":"KFP_POD_NAME"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:valueFrom':
                    .: {}
                    'f:fieldRef':
                      .: {}
                      'f:apiVersion': {}
                      'f:fieldPath': {}
                'k:{"name":"KFP_POD_UID"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:valueFrom':
                    .: {}
                    'f:fieldRef':
                      .: {}
                      'f:apiVersion': {}
                      'f:fieldPath': {}
                'k:{"name":"KFP_RUN_ID"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:valueFrom':
                    .: {}
                    'f:fieldRef':
                      .: {}
                      'f:apiVersion': {}
                      'f:fieldPath': {}
                'k:{"name":"KFP_V2_IMAGE"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
                'k:{"name":"KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
                'k:{"name":"WORKFLOW_ID"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:valueFrom':
                    .: {}
                    'f:fieldRef':
                      .: {}
                      'f:apiVersion': {}
                      'f:fieldPath': {}
              'f:envFrom': {}
              'f:image': {}
              'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:resources': {}
              'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
              'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
              'f:volumeMounts':
                .: {}
                'k:{"mountPath":"/kfp-launcher"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:mountPath': {}
                  'f:name': {}
            'k:{"name":"wait"}':
              .: {}
              'f:command': {}
              'f:env':
                .: {}
                'k:{"name":"ARGO_CONTAINER_NAME"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
                'k:{"name":"ARGO_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_EXECUTOR"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
                'k:{"name":"ARGO_INCLUDE_SCRIPT_OUTPUT"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
                'k:{"name":"ARGO_POD_NAME"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:valueFrom':
                    .: {}
                    'f:fieldRef':
                      .: {}
                      'f:apiVersion': {}
                      'f:fieldPath': {}
                'k:{"name":"GODEBUG"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
              'f:image': {}
              'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:resources':
                .: {}
                'f:limits':
                  .: {}
                  'f:cpu': {}
                  'f:memory': {}
                'f:requests':
                  .: {}
                  'f:cpu': {}
                  'f:memory': {}
              'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
              'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
              'f:volumeMounts':
                .: {}
                'k:{"mountPath":"/argo/podmetadata"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:mountPath': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                'k:{"mountPath":"/argo/secret/mlpipeline-minio-artifact"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:mountPath': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:readOnly': {}
                'k:{"mountPath":"/mainctrfs/kfp-launcher"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:mountPath': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                'k:{"mountPath":"/var/run/docker.sock"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:mountPath': {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:readOnly': {}
          'f:dnsPolicy': {}
          'f:enableServiceLinks': {}
          'f:initContainers':
            .: {}
            'k:{"name":"kfp-launcher"}':
              .: {}
              'f:command': {}
              'f:env':
                .: {}
                'k:{"name":"ARGO_CONTAINER_NAME"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
                'k:{"name":"ARGO_INCLUDE_SCRIPT_OUTPUT"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:name': {}
                  'f:value': {}
              'f:image': {}
              'f:imagePullPolicy': {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:resources': {}
              'f:terminationMessagePath': {}
              'f:terminationMessagePolicy': {}
              'f:volumeMounts':
                .: {}
                'k:{"mountPath":"/kfp-launcher"}':
                  .: {}
                  'f:mountPath': {}
                  'f:name': {}
          'f:restartPolicy': {}
          'f:schedulerName': {}
          'f:securityContext': {}
          'f:serviceAccount': {}
          'f:serviceAccountName': {}
          'f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds': {}
          'f:volumes':
            .: {}
            'k:{"name":"docker-sock"}':
              .: {}
              'f:hostPath':
                .: {}
                'f:path': {}
                'f:type': {}
              'f:name': {}
            'k:{"name":"kfp-launcher"}':
              .: {}
              'f:emptyDir': {}
              'f:name': {}
            'k:{"name":"mlpipeline-minio-artifact"}':
              .: {}
              'f:name': {}
              'f:secret':
                .: {}
                'f:defaultMode': {}
                'f:items': {}
                'f:secretName': {}
            'k:{"name":"podmetadata"}':
              .: {}
              'f:downwardAPI':
                .: {}
                'f:defaultMode': {}
                'f:items': {}
              'f:name': {}
    - manager: k3s
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2021-12-31T10:12:24Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:status':
          'f:conditions':
            'k:{"type":"ContainersReady"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastProbeTime': {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:message': {}
              'f:reason': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
            'k:{"type":"Initialized"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastProbeTime': {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
            'k:{"type":"Ready"}':
              .: {}
              'f:lastProbeTime': {}
              'f:lastTransitionTime': {}
              'f:message': {}
              'f:reason': {}
              'f:status': {}
              'f:type': {}
          'f:containerStatuses': {}
          'f:hostIP': {}
          'f:initContainerStatuses': {}
          'f:phase': {}
          'f:podIP': {}
          'f:podIPs':
            .: {}
            'k:{"ip":"10.42.0.101"}':
              .: {}
              'f:ip': {}
          'f:startTime': {}
    - manager: argoexec
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2021-12-31T10:12:25Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        'f:metadata':
          'f:annotations':
            'f:workflows.argoproj.io/outputs': {}
status:
  phase: Failed
  conditions:
    - type: Initialized
      status: 'True'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-12-31T10:12:23Z'
    - type: Ready
      status: 'False'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-12-31T10:12:21Z'
      reason: ContainersNotReady
      message: 'containers with unready status: [wait main]'
    - type: ContainersReady
      status: 'False'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-12-31T10:12:21Z'
      reason: ContainersNotReady
      message: 'containers with unready status: [wait main]'
    - type: PodScheduled
      status: 'True'
      lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2021-12-31T10:12:21Z'
  hostIP: 10.19.64.214
  podIP: 10.42.0.101
  podIPs:
    - ip: 10.42.0.101
  startTime: '2021-12-31T10:12:21Z'
  initContainerStatuses:
    - name: kfp-launcher
      state:
        terminated:
          exitCode: 0
          reason: Completed
          startedAt: '2021-12-31T10:12:22Z'
          finishedAt: '2021-12-31T10:12:22Z'
          containerID: >-
            docker://fbf8b39a3bab8065b54e9a3b25a678e07e0880ef61f9e78abe92f9fa205a73c4
      lastState: {}
      ready: true
      restartCount: 0
      image: 'library/gcr.io/ml-pipeline/kfp-launcher:1.8.7'
      imageID: >-
        docker-pullable://library/gcr.io/ml-pipeline/kfp-launcher@sha256:8b3f14d468a41c319e95ef4047b7823c64480fd1980c3d5b369c8412afbc684f
      containerID: >-
        docker://fbf8b39a3bab8065b54e9a3b25a678e07e0880ef61f9e78abe92f9fa205a73c4
  containerStatuses:
    - name: main
      state:
        terminated:
          exitCode: 1
          reason: Error
          startedAt: '2021-12-31T10:12:23Z'
          finishedAt: '2021-12-31T10:12:23Z'
          containerID: >-
            docker://26faae59907e5a4207960ee9d15d9d350587c5be7db31c3e8f0ec97e72c6d2cf
      lastState: {}
      ready: false
      restartCount: 0
      image: 'python:3.7'
      imageID: >-
        docker-pullable://python@sha256:3908249ce6b2d28284e3610b07bf406c3035bc2e3ce328711a2b42e1c5a75fc1
      containerID: >-
        docker://26faae59907e5a4207960ee9d15d9d350587c5be7db31c3e8f0ec97e72c6d2cf
      started: false
    - name: wait
      state:
        terminated:
          exitCode: 1
          reason: Error
          message: >-
            path /tmp/outputs/Output/data does not exist in archive
            /tmp/argo/outputs/artifacts/add-Output.tgz
          startedAt: '2021-12-31T10:12:23Z'
          finishedAt: '2021-12-31T10:12:25Z'
          containerID: >-
            docker://66b6306eb81ac2abb1fbf2609d7375a00f92891f1c827680a45962cbb1ec3c0a
      lastState: {}
      ready: false
      restartCount: 0
      image: 'library/gcr.io/ml-pipeline/argoexec:v3.1.6-patch-license-compliance'
      imageID: >-
        docker-pullable://library/gcr.io/ml-pipeline/argoexec@sha256:44cf8455a51aa5b961d1a86f65e39adf5ffca9bdcd33a745c3b79f430b7439e0
      containerID: >-
        docker://66b6306eb81ac2abb1fbf2609d7375a00f92891f1c827680a45962cbb1ec3c0a
      started: false
  qosClass: Burstable
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: podmetadata
      downwardAPI:
        items:
          - path: annotations
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.annotations
        defaultMode: 420
    - name: docker-sock
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/docker.sock
        type: Socket
    - name: kfp-launcher
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: mlpipeline-minio-artifact
      secret:
        secretName: mlpipeline-minio-artifact
        items:
          - key: accesskey
            path: accesskey
          - key: secretkey
            path: secretkey
        defaultMode: 420
    - name: default-editor-token-8lmfr
      secret:
        secretName: default-editor-token-8lmfr
        defaultMode: 420
  initContainers:
    - name: kfp-launcher
      image: 'library/gcr.io/ml-pipeline/kfp-launcher:1.8.7'
      command:
        - launcher
        - '--copy'
        - /kfp-launcher/launch
      env:
        - name: ARGO_CONTAINER_NAME
          value: kfp-launcher
        - name: ARGO_INCLUDE_SCRIPT_OUTPUT
          value: 'false'
      resources: {}
      volumeMounts:
        - name: kfp-launcher
          mountPath: /kfp-launcher
        - name: default-editor-token-8lmfr
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  containers:
    - name: wait
      image: 'library/gcr.io/ml-pipeline/argoexec:v3.1.6-patch-license-compliance'
      command:
        - argoexec
        - wait
        - '--loglevel'
        - info
      env:
        - name: ARGO_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: ARGO_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_EXECUTOR
          value: docker
        - name: GODEBUG
          value: x509ignoreCN=0
        - name: ARGO_CONTAINER_NAME
          value: wait
        - name: ARGO_INCLUDE_SCRIPT_OUTPUT
          value: 'false'
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 500m
          memory: 512Mi
        requests:
          cpu: 10m
          memory: 32Mi
      volumeMounts:
        - name: podmetadata
          mountPath: /argo/podmetadata
        - name: docker-sock
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
        - name: mlpipeline-minio-artifact
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /argo/secret/mlpipeline-minio-artifact
        - name: kfp-launcher
          mountPath: /mainctrfs/kfp-launcher
        - name: default-editor-token-8lmfr
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    - name: main
      image: 'library/python:3.7'
      command:
        - /kfp-launcher/launch
        - '--mlmd_server_address'
        - $(METADATA_GRPC_SERVICE_HOST)
        - '--mlmd_server_port'
        - $(METADATA_GRPC_SERVICE_PORT)
        - '--runtime_info_json'
        - $(KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO)
        - '--container_image'
        - $(KFP_V2_IMAGE)
        - '--task_name'
        - add
        - '--pipeline_name'
        - pipeline/v2add
        - '--run_id'
        - $(KFP_RUN_ID)
        - '--run_resource'
        - workflows.argoproj.io/$(WORKFLOW_ID)
        - '--namespace'
        - $(KFP_NAMESPACE)
        - '--pod_name'
        - $(KFP_POD_NAME)
        - '--pod_uid'
        - $(KFP_POD_UID)
        - '--pipeline_root'
        - ''
        - '--enable_caching'
        - $(ENABLE_CACHING)
        - '--'
        - a=1
        - b=7
        - '--'
      args:
        - sh
        - '-c'
        - >

          if ! [ -x "$(command -v pip)" ]; then
              python3 -m ensurepip || python3 -m ensurepip --user || apt-get install python3-pip
          fi


          PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 python3 -m pip install --quiet    
          --no-warn-script-location 'kfp==1.8.10' && "$0" "$@"
        - sh
        - '-ec'
        - >
          program_path=$(mktemp -d)

          printf "%s" "$0" > "$program_path/ephemeral_component.py"

          python3 -m kfp.v2.components.executor_main                        
          --component_module_path                        
          "$program_path/ephemeral_component.py"                         "$@"
        - |+

          import kfp
          from kfp.v2 import dsl
          from kfp.v2.dsl import *
          from typing import *

          def add(a: float, b: float) -> float:
              '''Calculates sum of two arguments'''
              return a + b

        - '--executor_input'
        - '{{$}}'
        - '--function_to_execute'
        - add
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: metadata-grpc-configmap
            optional: true
      env:
        - name: KFP_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: KFP_POD_UID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.uid
        - name: KFP_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: WORKFLOW_ID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''workflows.argoproj.io/workflow'']'
        - name: KFP_RUN_ID
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''pipeline/runid'']'
        - name: ENABLE_CACHING
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: 'metadata.labels[''pipelines.kubeflow.org/enable_caching'']'
        - name: KFP_V2_IMAGE
          value: 'library/python:3.7'
        - name: KFP_V2_RUNTIME_INFO
          value: >-
            {"inputParameters": {"a": {"type": "DOUBLE"}, "b": {"type":
            "DOUBLE"}}, "inputArtifacts": {}, "outputParameters": {"Output":
            {"type": "DOUBLE", "path": "/tmp/outputs/Output/data"}},
            "outputArtifacts": {}}
        - name: ARGO_CONTAINER_NAME
          value: main
        - name: ARGO_INCLUDE_SCRIPT_OUTPUT
          value: 'false'
      resources: {}
      volumeMounts:
        - name: kfp-launcher
          mountPath: /kfp-launcher
        - name: default-editor-token-8lmfr
          readOnly: true
          mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
      terminationMessagePolicy: File
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Never
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  serviceAccountName: default-editor
  serviceAccount: default-editor
  nodeName: iz1bb01rvtheuakv3h25ntz
  securityContext: {}
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  tolerations:
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
      tolerationSeconds: 300
    - key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
      operator: Exists
      effect: NoExecute
      tolerationSeconds: 300
  priority: 0
  enableServiceLinks: true
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
```

[image]

I don't know why it can't find the PipelineName?
[image]
[image]